# Simple HTML DOM parser; returns 0 issue

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using this code:

```
$url = 'http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/mp.php?mpn=' . $avariable . '&mpc=' . $anothervariable . '&house=commons&display=everyvote#divisions';
$options = array('http' => array('header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4"));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);

foreach($html->find('table.votes tr.odd,tr.even') as $tr) {
  if ($tr->find('td', 3) == '<td>absent</td>') { $voted = $voted + 1; }
  $possible = $possible + 1;
}
```

I'm getting the correct values for some of the pages such as

```
http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/mp.php?mpn=Flick_Drummond&mpc=Portsmouth_South&house=commons&display=everyvote#divisions
```

and

```
http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/mp.php?mpn=Kelly_Tolhurst&mpc=Rochester_and_Strood&house=commons&display=everyvote#divisions
```

but when I reached

```
http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/mp.php?mpn=Jim_Dowd&mpc=Lewisham_West_and_Penge&house=commons&display=everyvote#divisions
```

or

```
http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/mp.php?mpn=Tom_Watson&mpc=West_Bromwich_East&house=commons&display=everyvote#divisions
```

it gives me 0 when there are several values that should be counted.

I've looked at each page's layout and they are all the same so I'm stumped as to why it's returning 0 on some pages.

EDIT:

when I remove the check

```
if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes))
```

it returns

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find()
```

I don't understand this as all 4 pages I mentioned above have similar structures

Answer (score 0):

file_get_html($url) will get the page source from the url destination. the page source is not necessarily the elements you see on the page. Before browser bring all the elements and display to you, it would do some rendering, such like js execution and some error correction. maybe pause the js execution in browser and see what the page gives you.